# Fourier transform of positive bump functions with constant piece

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, distribution-theory, smooth-functions

Consider a bump function $f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with the property
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1\qquad \forall x\in (a,b)\,,
\\
0\qquad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
for some $\epsilon>0$. Basically this is just a constant function on an interval $(a,b)$ and interpolates to zero smoothly and monotonically within some small window $\epsilon$ such that $f$ is smooth and compactly supported. There are two "scales" available in the function: $\Delta = b-a>0$ and $\epsilon>0$.

> **Question:** how much is known about the Fourier transform in terms of $\Delta,\epsilon$ --- in particular, the asymptotic behaviour --- in terms of these two numbers?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Properties_and_uses) (which I guess is based on stationary phase approximation), the case of the standard bump function using $e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$ is known to have asymptotics $O(|k|^{-3/4}e^{-\sqrt{k}})$. So it decays faster than any polynomial, but it does have "non-analytic" part due to the $1/|k|$. What I am trying to understand is the expected behaviour of the function $f$ in terms of $\Delta,\epsilon$.

On the one hand, Gaussian functions $g(x) = e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}$ (which has only one scale determined by its width $\sigma$) is smooth and not compactly supported, and the Fourier transform is also a Gaussian $\tilde{g}(k)\sim e^{-\sigma^2 k^2}$ with width $\sigma^{-1}$. On the other hand, "distributions" like the [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) $r(x)$ is compactly supported but discontinous at the edge; it has sinc function as its Fourier transform, so $\tilde{r}(k)\sim \sin(k \Delta )/k$, which gives $O(1/|k|)$. My intuition (from doing physics) is that if $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ as required above, then it should be "in between":
\begin{align}
\tilde{f}(k) \sim O(|k|^{-\alpha}e^{-k^{\beta}})
\end{align}
where, if I have to guess, $0<\alpha <1$ and $0< \beta <1$. Therefore, I can ask a more precise question: *Is this guess correct and/or well-known*?

If it is well-known, it would be great if you could point to a paper/book/etc. If it is not correct and there is an argument or counterexample, that would be great. If it is somehow trivial (and I am not seeing it) I would appreciate any hints on the strategy. Ideally it would be nice to know some kind of dependence of $\alpha,\beta$ with $\Delta,\epsilon$, but I think it may not be the case and the latter just appear in the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $f$ on the intervals $(a-\epsilon,a)$ and $(b,b+\epsilon),$ e.g. that is has to be monotonic on each of those intervals, or can the function have a spike of arbitrary size?

Comment: You can get such a bump function as the convolution of the indicator function of $(a-\varepsilon/2, b+\varepsilon/2)$ and the exponential you described with suppport in $(-\varepsilon/2, \varepsilon/2)$. The Fourier transform is then the product.

Comment: @md2perpe you are right, I want something that has to be monotonic on those intervals, so it decreases nicely to zero.

Comment: @Jochen maybe I am misunderstanding something you are suggesting, but I don't see how this convolution is smooth since the exponential would have been discontinuous on that restricted support. I do get the point of your suggestion - since if it works, then convolution theorem guarantees that the asymptotics are just products of the two separate asymptotics of each Fourier transforms. I am sort of looking for "loose" results where I don't need to use Gaussians though (it's just an extreme example).

Comment: @Everiana. Take $\rho_\epsilon\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $\rho_\epsilon\geq 0$ with $\rho_\epsilon(x)=0$ when $|x|>\epsilon$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho_\epsilon(x) \, dx = 1.$ Then $\phi_\epsilon:=\mathbf{1}_{[a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]}*\rho_\epsilon$ has value $1$ on $[a,b]$ and value $0$ on $(-\infty,a-2]\cup[b+2\epsilon,\infty).$ Here $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is the indicator function on the set $A,$ i.e. $\mathbf{1}_A(x)$ has value $1$ if $x\in A$ and value $0$ if $x\not\in A.$ Also $\phi_\epsilon\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$

Comment: Do you expect finer estimations compared to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem, which provides estimates of Fourier transform of function with compact support?